# Try to use PHP to connect Facebook, got the message : "Invalid verification code format"

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

the call back url is  :

```
$config['callback_url'] = "https://test/FB/test/index.php";
```

And I have updated the FB App settings:

**Privacy Policy URL
Terms of Service URL
Site URL**

I am trying this way, and the result of `$html` is :

```
{"error":{"message":"Invalid verification code format.","type":"OAuthException","code":100,"fbtrace_id":"GdN0ZXtU1yr"}}
```

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
        session_start();
        require 'config.php';
        require '../src/facebook.php';

        // Create our Application instance (replace this with your appId and secret).
        $facebook = new Facebook(array(
                'appId'  => $config['App_ID'],
                'secret' => $config['App_Secret'],
                'default_graph_version' => 'v2.1',
                'cookie' => true
        ));
        $token_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?"
                ."client_id=".$config['App_ID']."&redirect_uri=".urlencode($config['callback_url'])
                ."&client_secret=".$config['App_Secret']."&code=".$_GET['code'];

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $token_url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,0);

        $html = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $html;
?>
```

Please advise why it doesn't work.
Thanks a lots.

Comment: The Facebook PHP SDK has methods for this, so you should not need to make your own cURL requests “in parallel”.

Comment: Improved the language and made code formatting changes